# Pause and resume Timer in ViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I want to pause and resume timer in viewcontroller which is displayed as subview in mainviewcontroller. Play/Pause button in mainviewcontroller when pressed it displays view controller as subview as well as plays audio.

Have this NSTimer in view controller

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.6
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateView:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

 - (void)updateView:(NSTimer *)theTimer
 {


 if  (index < [textArray count])
    {


        self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];
        self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
        index++;



} else {

   index = 0;

 }
```

I want to pause and resume timer when play/pause button is pressed in mainviewcontroller. How can i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.6
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateView:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

[myTimer invalidate];
```

/*
Stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop.
*/

```
[myTimer fire];
```

/*
You can use this method to fire a repeating timer without interrupting its regular firing schedule. If the timer is non-repeating, it is automatically invalidated after firing, even if its scheduled fire date has not arrived. 
*/

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want to pause and resume it through play/pause button and in my play pause button method i do have pause timer and resume timer but it is not working because i have one more timer in mainviewcontroller to display viewcontroller as subview

Comment: I think it does not matters - the way to play or pause anyone NSTimer is only to get his pointer after create it like NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval ...] . If you want to use this pointer in your class you need to save it in member variable of class.

Comment: So if i want to use this myTimer from viewcontroller in mainviewcontroller to pause and resume it. how can i do that

Comment: In what class do you create this timer? Assumed, you create it in MyClass. So you shall have a member variable m_myTimer AND a public method - (NSTimer*)getTimer in this class. The mainviewcontroller can now get the pointer to Timer over this method ...

Answer (score 2):

First you have to keep a reference of your timer in your interface-file:

```
NSTimer *myTimer;
```

In the implementation file you can simply connect and then refer to it:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.6
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(updateView:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];
```

To stop the timer call:

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

To start it again:

```
[myTimer fire];
```

See [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for more info about the NSTimer Class.